# Replace string value in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am new to C#, and need a little help, i know in PHP that i can to something like this

```
$SelectedEvent="event selected";

if (i > 0)
{
  $SelectedEvent = "event";
}
```

It replace a string easy, but in c# that is not working ok, here is example code i have that is not working

```
  string SelectedEvent = "event selected"; 

  if (i > 0)
    {
         SelectedEvent = "event"; 
    }
```

This is not working like in PHP, i can not override the varible?

Here is my example code

**EDITED**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{

    string SelectedEvent = "event selected";    


    if (i > 1)
    {
         string SelectedEvent = "event"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: This should work, what is the value of `i`?

Comment: It does work, what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Yeah, this should work fine.  What error are you getting?

Comment: This is not replace! btw it should work!

Comment: just made fiddle for you:https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ac7i5t

Comment: Are you sure that the two variables have the same scope?

Comment: You are declaring a new variable with the same name of the first one inside the if block effectively obscuring the outer one

Comment: Yes but i didnt know that i am new to c# :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not redeclare the variable twice but only modify its value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string SelectedEvent = "event selected";    
    if (i > 1)
    {
         SelectedEvent = "event"; 
    }

    // here you can use the SelectedEventVariable
    // its value will be "event selected" on the first and second
    // iterations and "event" on subsequent 
}
```

Comment: Txanks now it is ok, as i said i new to c#

Comment: Just curious--what's the @ symbol for?

Comment: @adv12, it was in the OP. I guess that's inside a Razor template and his question is incorrectly tagged with C#.

Comment: Yes i have forgot to remove it because it is much complex code only i needed this part, txanks